# Parsing div id with variable

Tags: php, javascript, parsing

First of all I appreciate that all members are trying to help each other.

I want div content by id in my javascript function. I've got function and it works fine with one div and it's content. But now I've got multiple records from DB, so to make div unique I have done following. where $i=$i+1 in while loop

```
<div id="<?php echo 'fvd'.$i; ?>" class="fake-checkbox star-checkbox"><a id="<?php echo 'tvd'.$i; ?>" onclick="respuestas('<?php echo $user_id1;?>'); return false;" href="#">Add to favourites</a></div>
```

so here I generate fvd1, tvd1 for next record fvd2,tv2 and so on
Below function process user id and get response by Ajax call and change caption from Add to favourites to Added to favourites and add class name 'checked' which change text color.

```
function respuestas(str) {
    var popID = str;

    var gett = document.getElementById('tvd1').innerHTML;

    if (gett == 'Add to favourites') {
        $.post('personals/addfavourite.php', {
            ref: popID
        }, function (data) {

            if (data == 'no') {
                alert('Sorry! something gone wrong!')
            } else if (data == 'yes') {

                var d = document.getElementById("fvd1");
                d.className = d.className + " checked";
                document.getElementById('tvd1').innerHTML = 'Added to favourites';
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Now how can I parse fvd2,tvd2 and so on in this function.
Any help will be much appreciated..Thanks

Comment: Just FYI - your JS function `respuestas` was missing an ending curly-brace...

Comment: Thanks but I don't think anything is missing..is it?

Comment: What is the resulting HTML? What are the errors in JavaScript console? Could you add `console.log(...)` calls to see what's in `elm`?  See here for [console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/tag/console)

Comment: thanks for your help Ondra, this problem is solved with Sean's suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
onclick="respuestas(this, '<?php echo $user_id1;?>');
```

and the first param would be the `<a>` so you can do

```
function respuestas(elm, str) {

    elm.getAttribute("id");

}
```

or so. (Not sure about the DOM method name)

BTW why don't you just put the `$i` to the call as well? Or maybe I didn't get the question right? If not, pls explain.

If you need to access the elements, well then you already have the `<a>` in `elm`, and the `<div>` is in `elm.parentElement`.

Check HTML DOM methods: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.parentElement

Comment: Thanks..but I need to collect two div element one change caption and other add class to div which change icon and text color..so I don't know how to do it

Comment: as you suggest I've tried to collect id with elm but not successful, I just want to catch $i and parse it like document.getElementById('tvd'.i).innerHTML;

Answer (score 0):

If you add your `$i` to the function parameters you can get each grouping dynamically

```
onclick="respuestas('<?php echo $user_id1;?>',<?php echo $i;?>); return false;"
```

and

```
function respuestas(str,num) {
    ...
    var gett = document.getElementById('tvd'+num).innerHTML;
    ...
    var d = document.getElementById("fvd"+num);
    ...
    document.getElementById('tvd'+num).innerHTML = 'Added to favourites';
    ...
}
```